# HFP/HSP profile in linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, pulse-audio, bluez

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and already installed BlueZ 5.37, PulseAudio 10.0, and ofono 1.20 (clone from github).

And I need to use phone like modem for transmitting my phone calls to computer. I paired my telephone with PC, made device trust and connect (all actions are successfully). I think problem with ofono, because I can play music (which use the A2DP) but if i want use hands free or headset profile - I have no sound on PC.

In pacmd (PulseAudio console tool) list-cards I see my bluetooth device, but Headset Audio Gateway HFP/HSP is not avalible. Also I tested it on different devices and computers.

Thank you in advice.